# Maintaining multiple forms of user guide for a Java application

Tags: java, html, pdf, documentation

I have a user guide for my application that I would like to provide both an HTML verson and a PDF version (and possible some other indexed version for a Java help). Are there any tools, preferably for maven that I could integrate into my build cycle that will convert from HTML to PDF? Currently I have a word doc format that I manually convert to PDF (and no HTML version available), which is prone to errors and really just a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a tool like [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/) and write the documentation in a scripting language (XML in their case). Then use the tool to transform the source to the target formats, e.g. HTML and PDF.

Comment: I think this is the more flexible solution here. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after a short search, I went on http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/ and if you have your HTML, it does the trick.

However, I prefer using a wiki for documentation. It has all advantages, since it can be edited in parallel, in multiple languages, and a lot of them have both static HTML export and PDF export.
I should recommend you Dokuwiki (and you can find your plugins at http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugins) because it's really easy to install and administrate, but you can also use any other one that have PDF and HTML export.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely take a more detailed look at those tools, but just in case I want to go to other forms other than PDF, it looks like DocBook is a little more flexible.